# How to fix else statement not activating

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a toggle switch for my background audio and a certain else statement won't work.

I have tried using else/else if and setting it up in a number of ways, but nothing seems to work.

```
function toggle() 
{

    if (!play()) {
        play();
    }
         //HERE IS THE ONE NOT WORKING//
    else {
        mute();
    }
}


function play() 
{
    //Sound Icon
    document.getElementById('muteB').src = 'MuteOff.png';
    //Play Music
    document.getElementById('mplayer').innerHTML = ('<source src="GameTheme.mp3" type="audio/mp3">');
}

    //MUTE FUNCTION
function mute() 
{
    //Sound Off Icon
    document.getElementById('muteB').src = 'MuteOn.png';
    //Stop Music
    document.getElementById('mplayer').innerHTML = ('');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="muteB" src="MuteOn.png" onclick="toggle()" />
```

I want the toggle() function to actually toggle the audio, but instead I can only turn it on, not off.

Comment: `if (!play())` but `play` isn't returning anything

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious, but what would I return there?

Comment: Your logic really does not make sense ... what you have basically reads as .... run the `play` method, if the result is not true, run the `play` method (again), otherwise run the `mute` method. So if the result of the `play` method is false, you run it twice.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback!  I believe I have it generally figured out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a global variable `isPlaying` and change is accordingly in both functions `play` and `mute`

```js
let isPlaying = false;

function toggle() {
    if (!isPlaying) {
        play();
    }
    //HERE IS THE ONE NOT WORKING//
    else {
        mute();
    }
}


function play() {
    //Sound Icon
    document.getElementById('muteB').src = 'MuteOff.png';
    //Play Music
    document.getElementById('mplayer').innerHTML = ('<source src="GameTheme.mp3" type="audio/mp3">');
    isPlaying = true;
}

//MUTE FUNCTION

function mute() {
    //Sound Off Icon
    document.getElementById('muteB').src = 'MuteOn.png';
    //Stop Music
    document.getElementById('mplayer').innerHTML = ('');
    isPlaying = false;
}
```